# how to fetch user related tables from live sever with drush sql-sync

Tags: drush

If you have a live server where some people have registered to your iste and you push new content from your dev,server regularly. What is the best workflow to fetch user related data from the server before you sql-sync and r sync an updated site to the live server with drush?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to push your database from dev to live.  Instead, push just the code from dev -> stage -> live, and pull the database in the other direction.

There are a number of solutions for moving content from dev or staging to live.  One option is the [content staging](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_staging) module; other people use [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import new data.